# PHP - Sum multiple array column individually

Tags: php, arrays

I have multiple array like

```
$arr = [10, 20, 30, 40];
$arr2 = [10, 20, 30, 40];
... etc
```

I need to do sum of their column like

```
$new = [20, 40, 60, 80]
```

I have tried with `array_sum` but it return sum of the rows

Comment: I wonder if this is an XY Problem.  Where is this data coming from?  How are these arrays being declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_sum` is the right approach, but you'll first need to *transpose* your two arrays (that is, convert the rows into columns). The easiest way to do this in PHP is to pass null as the first parameter to `array_map`:

```
$input = array_map(null, $arr, $arr2);
```

(This behaviour is described in the PHP docs here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

Once your array is transposed, you can map `array_sum` to each row to achieve your desired result:

```
print_r(array_map('array_sum', $input));
```

> Array
> (
> [0] => 20
> [1] => 40
> [2] => 60
> [3] => 80
> )

See https://3v4l.org/AJtZa for a full example

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, you might be interested to see how to build the logic of summing the columns of a range of arrays yourself (i.e. not depend on the magic of in-built PHP functions):

```
<?php
$arr = [10, 20, 30, 40];
$arr1 = [10, 20, 30, 40];
$arr2 = [10, 20, 30, 40];

$sum = sumCols($arr, $arr1, $arr2);

function sumCols(...$arrays)
{
    $sumCols = [];
    foreach ($arrays as $arr) {
          foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
              (isset($sumCols[$key])) ? $sumCols[$key] += $value : $sumCols[$key] = $value;
          }
    }
    return $sumCols;
}
```

Output `$sum`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 30
    [1] => 60
    [2] => 90
    [3] => 120
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that accepts any number of arrays as input.

```php
$arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
$arr2 = [10, 20, 30, 40];
$arr3 = [100, 200, 300, 400];

$result = array_map(
  fn(...$i) => array_sum($i),
  $arr1,
  $arr2,
  $arr3
  // more arrays can be added here
);
```

**It works fine in PHP 7.4 or newer.**

Check it [online](https://3v4l.org/vD0qh).

---

PHP 7.4 is required above for the [arrow function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php).

However, using an arrow function is not mandatory. A classical anonymous function can be used instead:

```php
$arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
$arr2 = [10, 20, 30, 40];
$arr3 = [100, 200, 300, 400];

$result = array_map(
  function(... $i) { return array_sum($i); },
  $arr1,
  $arr2,
  $arr3
);
```

**This version works with PHP 5.6 or newer.**

Check it [online](https://3v4l.org/KPD5H).

---

PHP 5.6 is needed above to use `...` for the [variable-length argument list](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php).

However, it is not required either. The function [`func_get_args()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) can be used instead to get the list of arguments:

```php
$arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
$arr2 = [10, 20, 30, 40];
$arr3 = [100, 200, 300, 400];

$result = array_map(
  function() { return array_sum(func_get_args()); },
  $arr1,
  $arr2,
  $arr3
);
```

**This version works with PHP 5.4 or newer.**

Check it [online](https://3v4l.org/dViC7).

---

PHP 5.4 is needed above for the [short array syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

However, it is not required either. The old, long syntax for arrays can be used instead:

```php
$arr1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
$arr2 = array(10, 20, 30, 40);
$arr3 = array(100, 200, 300, 400);

$result = array_map(
  function() { return array_sum(func_get_args()); },
  $arr1,
  $arr2,
  $arr3
);
```

**This version works with PHP 5.3 and newer.**

Check it [online](https://3v4l.org/rtPBG).

---

PHP 5.3 is needed above for the [anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). It is not needed either.

The anonymous function can be replaced by a function created using `create_function()` and this makes the code compatible even with PHP 4.
However, besides being completely useless, the old [`create_function()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) function has been deprecated in PHP 7.2 and completely removed in PHP 8.0 for good reasons.

But a regular function can be used instead of an anonymous function:

```php
$arr1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
$arr2 = array(10, 20, 30, 40);
$arr3 = array(100, 200, 300, 400);

$result = array_map('add_values', $arr1, $arr2, $arr3);
function add_values() {
  return array_sum(func_get_args());
}
```

**This version works with PHP 4.0 or newer.**
PHP 4.0 has been [released](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-4.php#4.0.0) 21 years ago (in May 2000.)

Check it [online](https://3v4l.org/ce2ZM).